# How to get only the Full name of previous Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, groovy, hudson

I would like to send the full name of the previous build that was received by using the following:

```
Run previousBuild = steps.currentBuild.rawBuild.getPreviousBuildInProgress()
```

in order to send to getItemByFullName as you can see below,

```
Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(previousBuildPath)
```

I tried to find it in the Run class hudson Documentation with no success.

while printing previousBuild I got the name with the build number like:

```
 previousBuild- > project_neme/build_name #100
```

But I want to get only the name with no String substring cutting.

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all. What exactly do you mean by wanting to get the name? The name of the job? Or the number of the previous build? The only difference between different builds for the same job in Jenkins is the build number. A specific build consist of the job name/path + its unique build number, that's all.

Comment: I want to get only the name not the number

Comment: Is this not already available to you via `env.JOB_NAME` in this case? Sorry, not sure why you want to go through previous builds to get the job's name, but I might be missing something.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as I wrote in my question, I need to get the full name of the **Previous Build**, I cannot check  `env.JOB_NAME` for other buld

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for display name property. Display name is the name given to each build (if you update it during execution) followed by a build number. The display name will only return the build name.
`Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('JobName').getLastBuild().displayName`

Read here
https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Job.html